# How do I assign a list to the values of an associative array?

Tags: bash

This is basically what I am trying to do: to assign a list to the value of an associative array.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash
declare -A params

params[n]=(200 400 600 800)
params[p]=(0.2 0.4)
```

But I got this error:

```
line 4: params[n]: cannot assign list to array member
line 5: params[p]: cannot assign list to array member
```

Is there any way to get around this problem ?

Comment: The notation you've written appears to be attempting to assign arrays to values of an array.  While this works in some other languages, it does not work in bash. In bash, an array member may not be an array, it is merely a string.  How you get around it depends on what you're trying to achieve. If you could add a hint about your end goal to your question, we'd be better able to suggest an alternative.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
declare -A params
params=([n]="200 400 600 800" [p]="0.2 0.4")
declare -p params
```

Output:

```
declare -A params='([n]="200 400 600 800" [p]="0.2 0.4" )'
```

Comment: If I write it like this , Would I be able to iterate through both the keys and the values later on ?

Answer (score 19):

Essentially, you want 2 dimensional array:

1st dimension is de-referenced by 'n' or 'p'.
2nd dimension is de-referenced like a normal array.

`bash` does not support multi-dimensional arrays.

You are left with these options:

1. Use combined index as array index in single-dimensional array.

   ```
   declare -A params
   params[n,0]=200
   params[n,1]=400 
   params[n,2]=600 
   params[n,3]=800
   params[p,0]=0.2
   params[p,1]=0.4
   ```
2. Use 2 level dereferencing:

   ```
   declare -A params

   #Declare 2 normal arrays.
   array1=(200 400 600 800)
   array2=(0.2 0.4)

   #Use the main array to hold the names of these arrays.
   params[n]=array1[@]
   params[p]=array2[@]

   #use the array.
   printf "%s\n" "${!params[n]}"
   printf "%s\n" "${!params[p]}"
   ```
3. Good old 2 independent arrays:

   ```
   param_n=(200 400 600 800)
   param_p=(0.2 0.4)
   ```

Using these methods, you can iterate through the arrays even when the values contain spaces.

Answer (score 5):

Did you mean to store the lists as elements `n` and `p` in an Associative Array? Like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A params

params[n]="200 400 600 800"
params[p]="0.2 0.4"

for i in ${!params[@]}; do 
    echo "params[$i] = ${params[$i]}"
done

exit 0
```

**Output**

```
$ bash aalist.sh
params[n] = 200 400 600 800
params[p] = 0.2 0.4
```

Answer (score 0):

Most moments when we want multi-dimentional arrays because of the fact that we like the idea to "store" data this way and to re-call them from there that way, we do not focus on what we actually try to achieve. And that multi-dimentional arrays are not mandatory to reach that goal in many cases.

Shells are not good in such things. BUT if you need to solve it in shell enviroment consider functions and methods to parse multiple single-dimentional arrays so that you achieve the same effect but without the issues you have to deal with by using "pseudo" multi-dimentional arrays in shell enviroments. Especially because shell scripts are made for being "helpers" and consider what happens when shells or their systems update and your pseudo solution do not work no more.